# camera source code for android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, camera

I need some help. the thing is I doing an app on namecard reader and need to use the camera function to take pictures. but how do I make my app able to view the mutiple pic that I have save without having to exit the app and go to the gallery? below is the camera source code that I use.. thank

`

CameraMainActivity.Java

```
private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1337;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private ImageView imageView;
private Button save, capture;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_main);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);
    capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capture);
    capture.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void captureImage() {
    // Capture image from camera

        Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

}

public void pickImage() {
    // To pick a image from file system
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            try {
                // We need to recycle unused bitmaps
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                }
                InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                        data.getData());
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                stream.close();
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                }
                bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                if (data.getExtras().get("data") == null)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No image returned", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);



        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_camera_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v == save) {
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
        Bitmap bitmap = drawable.getBitmap();
        File sdCardDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File image = new File(sdCardDirectory, "test.png");
        boolean success = false;

        // Encode the file as a PNG image.
        FileOutputStream outStream;
        try {

            outStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
            /* 100 to keep full quality of the image */

            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
            success = true;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (success) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Image saved with success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Error during image saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else if (v == capture) {
        captureImage();
    }

}
```

}

i'm using a button to launch the camera

main.xml

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/takeviewpic"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Take/View Pic" />
```

Android Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.landscape" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:name="sp.com.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="main" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".NameCardList" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".DetailForm" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".EditPreferences" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".NameCardMap" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SmsReceiver" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CameraMainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
    />
</application>
```

`

Comment: You can save Image in IO File Manger by creating your application folder. And fetch the image from that folder and show it on Gallery or Image View.

Answer (score 2):

My this camera example can help you:--

```
import android.hardware.Camera;

import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

import android.util.Log;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Toast;


public class Main extends Activity {

  private final static String DEBUG_TAG = "MakePhotoActivity";

  private Camera camera;

  private int cameraId = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);


 if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {

          Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
else {

          cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();

          camera = Camera.open(cameraId);

          if (cameraId < 0) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.",

                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          }

        }

}

 public void onClick(View view) {

    camera.takePicture(null, null,new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));

  }

private int findFrontFacingCamera()
 {

int cameraId = -1;

    // Search for the front facing camera

    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++)

{

CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();

 Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);

 if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)

{
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Camera found");

       cameraId = i;

     break;

     }

   }

  return cameraId;

  }

@Override

 protected void onPause() 
{

 if (camera != null) 
{


    camera.release();

    camera = null;

 }

super.onPause();

}



}
```

And another class of photo handler..!!!:-

```
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 import java.util.Date;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.hardware.Camera;
 import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
 import android.os.Environment;
 import android.provider.SyncStateContract.Constants;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.Toast;

  public class PhotoHandler implements PictureCallback {
private final Context context;

  public PhotoHandler(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    File pictureFileDir = getDir();

    if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {

      Toast.makeText(context, "Can't create directory to save image.",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      return;

    }

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
    String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    String photoFile = "Picture_" + date + ".jpg";

    String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;

    File pictureFile = new File(filename);

    try {
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
      fos.write(data);
      fos.close();
      Toast.makeText(context, "New Image saved:" + photoFile,
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception error) {

      Toast.makeText(context, "Image could not be saved.",
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }

  private File getDir() {
    File sdDir = Environment
      .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    return new File(sdDir, "CameraAPIDemo");
  }

 }
```

If u want something else plz add comments...!!!!!

Comment: Ruchit Shah - do u have the full file for this example? I dun know how to put it in my program. need to see the full file with xml to understand how to put in the source code. sorry to trouble u :)

Comment: [Camera Gallery](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-select-multiple-photos-from-gallery/)          May this link can help you...!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Put up an activity with an ImageView (or ImageViews) and set the source on them to the files you created.