# Android Camera button cannot take photo

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I have a camera project and it can take picture but when I press take picture button twice rapidly it crashes.

The line number 71 in LogCat is **camera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, myPictureCallback_RAW, myPictureCallback_JPG);**

Here is the log file https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15065300/LogCat2.png

Here is the code

```
public class AndroidCamera extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

 Camera camera;
 SurfaceView surfaceView;
 SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
 boolean previewing = false;
 LayoutInflater controlInflater = null;

 Button buttonTakePicture;

 final int RESULT_SAVEIMAGE = 0;

   /** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);


       getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
       surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.camerapreview);
       surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
       surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

       controlInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
       View viewControl = controlInflater.inflate(R.layout.control, null);
       LayoutParams layoutParamsControl
        = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
       this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);


       buttonTakePicture = (Button)findViewById(R.id.takepicture);
       buttonTakePicture.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {    
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    camera.takePicture(myShutterCallback, myPictureCallback_RAW, myPictureCallback_JPG);
   }});

       LinearLayout layoutBackground = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.background);
       layoutBackground.setOnClickListener(new LinearLayout.OnClickListener(){


   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    buttonTakePicture.setEnabled(false);
    camera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);
   }});
   }

   AutoFocusCallback myAutoFocusCallback = new AutoFocusCallback(){

  @Override
  public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   buttonTakePicture.setEnabled(true);
  }};

   ShutterCallback myShutterCallback = new ShutterCallback(){

  @Override
  public void onShutter() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }};

 PictureCallback myPictureCallback_RAW = new PictureCallback(){

  @Override
  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }};

 PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPG = new PictureCallback(){

  @Override
  public void onPictureTaken(byte[] arg0, Camera arg1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   /*Bitmap bitmapPicture
    = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arg0, 0, arg0.length); */

   Uri uriTarget = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());

   OutputStream imageFileOS;
   try {
    imageFileOS = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uriTarget);
    imageFileOS.write(arg0);
    imageFileOS.flush();
    imageFileOS.close();

    Toast.makeText(AndroidCamera.this,
      "Image saved",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

   camera.startPreview();
  }};

 @Override
 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
   int height) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if(previewing){
   camera.stopPreview();
   previewing = false;
  }

  if (camera != null){
   try {
    camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);  
    camera.startPreview();
    previewing = true;
   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera = Camera.open();

 }

 @Override
 public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  camera.stopPreview();
  camera.release();
  camera = null;
  previewing = false;
 }
}
```

In the manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

May these code i have implemented can help you...!!!!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14495691/1626848

If any thing properly u want add in comments...!!!!